# Making ruby script into .exe

Tags: windows, scripts, ruby

Is there a way to make a windows executable from a ruby script on Ubuntu ? I've tried to achive that with ocra gem but I constantly getting  this error :

```
 /home/use/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/ocra-1.3.5/bin/ocra:41:in
`relative_path_from': undefined method path' for      
"/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@global":String (NoMethodError)
```

Also is there any way that a person could run this .exe without having ruby installed on his/her windows ? I'd like to share my script with "non-techie" friends

Answer (score 0):

OCRA is not compatible with Linux. See [here](https://github.com/larsch/ocra/issues/96) and [here](https://github.com/larsch/ocra/issues/98) and also on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112430/building-a-ruby-script-with-ocra-for-cross-platform-uses-but-i-get-the-relative). It should however work if you execute it on Windows. So that's a way to achieve what you want, but not on Ubuntu unfortunately.